# Range based for loop and range type

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17

With reference to the following text snippets mentioned under [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

> If range_expression is an expression of a class type C that has both a
>   member named begin and a member named end (regardless of the type or
>   accessibility of such member), then begin_expr is __range.begin() and
>   end_expr is __range.end();
>
> The member interpretation is used if the range type has a member named
>   begin and a member named end. This is done regardless of whether the
>   member is a type, data member, function, or enumerator, and regardless
>   of its accessibility. Thus a class like class meow { enum { begin = 1,
>   end = 2}; /* rest of class */ }; cannot be used with the range-based
>   for loop even if the namespace-scope begin/end functions are present.

Is the understanding correct that begin and end should only be the names of member functions of range type (returning possibly iterator type)? Curious to understand the technical reason behind the absence of any workaround for this constraint.

Answer (score 4):

You either need to provide non-member `begin` and `end` functions (or otherwise callable objects) that can be found through [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), or have member functions (or callable objects) explicitly named `begin` and `end` which takes no arguments, and which return iterator-like objects (i.e. they should support postfix `++` and dereference `*`, and of course could be compared using `==`).

As for "technical reasons", it's because range-based `for` loops are only syntactic sugar for a normal iterator `for` loop. And the compiler must know which functions to call for the "begin" and "end" iterators.

Comment: It may just be syntactic sugar, but it's oh such sweet, sweet sugary goodness!

Comment: They don't have to be member functions, which I think is what OP asks about.

Comment: So begin and end can only be function names in range type? No other member can have either name as stated in the quoted text in the question. Why couldn't the standard allow such a simple similarity in member naming convention?

Comment: @Vinod How would the compiler know which functions to call to get the iterators? Just "similarity" will make it all to ambiguous. Or do I misunderstand what you really mean? Anyway, for a ranged `for` loop, you either need to have something *callable* named `begin` and `end` as members, and that they return what is expected for iteration. Or (as already mentioned) specialize the `std::begin` and `std::end` functions.

Comment: In the free-function case you aren't supposed to specialized `std::begin`/`end`, but to provide your own to be found through ADL. If [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation) is correct (as it usually is), a specialization wouldn't be found at all since it cannot share your type's namespace ("non-ADL lookup is not performed").

Answer (score 3):

> Is the understanding correct that begin and end should only be the names of member functions of range type (returning possibly iterator type)?

No; actually, most of those are completely valid to be used as begin/end iterator pairs even though they are not member functions!

Here's one using data members:

```
struct A {
  A() : begin([this] { return array; }), end([this] { return array + 3; }) {}

  int array[3];
  std::function<int*()> begin;
  std::function<int*()> end;
};
```

Enumerators don't make sense though and types can't be accessed through `.`. Types that are named or with enumerators named `begin` and `end` and that should be iterable are probably very rare, which is probably why no special rule that excludes enumerators was introduced.